# How to avoid running tests multiple time whe integrating maven project to hudson/jenkins

Tags: maven, hudson, jenkins

I have integrated in Hudson a maven 3 project calling following sequence:

```
clean tomcat:redeploy site sonar:sonar
```

Problem is that JUnit is run 3 times, here the goal sequence I obtain:

```
>[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:i18n {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:generateAsync {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: mycom-check}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: extended-check}]  
>[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:i18n {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:generateAsync {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: mycom-check}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: extended-check}]  
>[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]  
>[INFO] **[surefire:test {execution: default-test}]**  
>[INFO] [gwt:compile {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]  
>[INFO] [***tomcat:redeploy*** {execution: default-cli}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:i18n {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:generateAsync {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: mycom-check}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: extended-check}]  
>[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [cobertura:instrument {execution: default-instrument}]  
>[INFO] [cobertura:instrument {execution: default-instrument}]  
>[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]  
>[INFO] **[surefire:test {execution: default-test}]**  
>[INFO] [cobertura:cobertura {execution: default-cli}]  
>[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]  
>[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]  
>[INFO] [***site:site*** {execution: default-site}]  
>[INFO]    task-segment: [sonar:sonar] (aggregator-style)  
>[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-cli}]  
>[INFO] [***sonar:sonar*** {execution: default-sonar}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:i18n {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [gwt:generateAsync {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: mycom-check}]  
>[INFO] [checkstyle:check {execution: extended-check}]  
>[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: default}]  
>[INFO] [cobertura:instrument {execution: default-instrument}]  
>[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]  
>[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]  
>[INFO] **[surefire:test {execution: default-test}]**  
>[INFO] [cobertura:cobertura {execution: default-cli}]
```

This is very problematic as a bug in Hudson makes it count 3 three times:
http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-1557
However it looked fixed in Jenkins:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2068

What I am surprised of is that the "cobertura" unit test run is done twice.
I am new to maven so I am not sure to understand very well the "lifecycle steps" resolution. In ant, target resolutions were done so as to execute only once each target.
My questions are:

- Why are these Cobertura unit tests run twice ? is a defect in my config, in Maven, in a plugin ?
- What can I test to try to understand ?
- In a general manner is there any Maven command available to preview the sequence that will be executed without doing the real exec ? I did  not find anything about that but would find it very useful.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are these Cobertura unit tests run twice ? is a defect in my
>   config, in Maven, in a plugin ?

Both `tomcat:redeploy` and `sonar:sonar` are running cobertura.  It is an issue with the maven configuration and can be fixed.

> What can I test to try to understand ?

In general you can run each goal separately to see what it does.

> In a general manner is there any Maven command available to preview the sequence that will be executed without doing the real exec ? I did not find anything about that but would find it very useful.

Usually the documentation of each goal indicates the life-cycle phases that get executed for that goal.  There is no `dry-run` option in maven.

Comment: Since yesterday I have tried changing the sequence to: `mvn clean tomcat:redeploy sonar:sonar site`. So inverting site and sonar goals. And it worked ! only one Cobertura JUnit test. I have no specific config for tomcat/site/sonar in my pom related to phase/goals execution.